# how to change the color of a Listview row on Swipe and let it remain till some other row is selected?

Tags: android, listview, colors, selector, swipe

I have used `SwipeListView` to display some contents. i want the color of my Listview to turn to black when it is touched,swiped and till some other row is selected. How can i do that? I have tried the following but it did not help.

```
 main.xml


 <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        android:id="@+id/example_swipe_lv_list"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
       android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
        swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"

        swipe:swipeMode="both"
        />
```

@drawable/list_selector

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="true" ></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Scrolling Listview items(Views) are reused. To keep the existing state of the View you have to use a ViewHolder concept.

Check out the links below:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

[findViewById vs View Holder Pattern in ListView adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289812/findviewbyid-vs-view-holder-pattern-in-listview-adapter)

Store the selected item in an Array. Keep checking if the item exists and change the background color in getView()