# Android L - Recycler view inside card view

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Is it suggested to use a recyclerView inside another cardview?
Would it be any performance issues with this?
Please let me know if anyone has used something of the same scenario?

Comment: Did you try implementing it?

Comment: Currently, I am having a list view inside the cardview item. And I was thinking of replacing it with recyclerview. Primarily, beacuse the cardview in my situation with the listview inside it, does drag and gets stuck somewhat while scrolling.

Comment: Try implementing View holder pattern for `ListView`. Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder and this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19289812/3879470

Comment: CardView is basically a FrameLayout with a custom background. What issues do you expect?