# Should i implement Recycling in ListView or that's the default behavior

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I learned about the recycling in ListView, GridView or any AdapterView and learned about it's best for performance and etc.

But i don't know is that (Recycling) is the default behavior in any ListView or should i override some methods and do that with myself.

I know about Customized ListView also, so in Customized ListView what is the case?

Comment: you can use the viewholder pattern to increase the performance as well as recycling of views. You can refer the link here for detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289812/findviewbyid-vs-view-holder-pattern-in-listview-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ListView recycles views as posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/799162

But as @Gautam told you, if you use the ViewHolder pattern you will increase the CPU performance because the ListView isn't going to create a lot of Views it's going to reuse them, as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder